# Room persistence library (dependency issue), MVVM design pattern

Tags: android, mvvm, build.gradle, android-room, androidx

Iam following MVVM tutorial and when adding [Room dependency](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#declaring_dependencies)

**1-** I got this this error in compile:

```
Note: Failed to read get kotlin metadata for [Ljava.lang.Object;@54d771f9

Note: Failed to read get kotlin metadata for [Ljava.lang.Object;@4c00a268

Note: Failed to read get kotlin metadata for [Ljava.lang.Object;@42104314

Note: Failed to read get kotlin metadata for [Ljava.lang.Object;@203b72ad
```

**2-** also this: (SOLVED)

```
error: cannot find symbol class of
```

when adding this code in `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private NoteViewModel noteViewModel;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //error is here in the ViewModelProviders.of
    noteViewModel = new ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);
    noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, notes -> {
        //update RecyclerView
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
 }
}
```

- build.gradle(project):

  ```
  repositories {
   google()
   jcenter()
   maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/" }
  }



  allprojects {
   repositories {
    google()
   jcenter()
   maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/" }
   }
  }
  ```
- build.gradle(app):

  ```
  room_version = "2.1.0-alpha06"

  implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
  annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `new`,
this will work:

`noteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);`

Answer (score 0):

The 2.1.0-alpha04 gets rid of these errors, but compiler puts out warnings about "mCallbacks in RoomDatabase has been deprecated" in a few places.

I am following the exact same tutorial on YouTube and have run into the same errors: "Note: Failed to read get kotlin metadata..." errors.

I've tried "2.1.0-alpha06", "2.1.0-alpha05" versions of the room dependencies along with the "maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/" dependency....again same errors.

Hoping for a better answer that cleans these errors up.

Comment: yes you are right, i've changed to 2.1.0-alpha04 till these errors fixed