# Cannot find version of 'androidx.arch', 'androidx.room', etc

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, androidx

I am experiencing the following issue when trying to build an android application. I have come across some android post on forcing or using a manual dependency resolution strategy. This does not seem to solve the problem.

A similar issue has been asked : [Similar stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336613/cannot-find-a-version-of-androidx-arch-corecore-common-that-satisfies-the-ver).

An issue was also opened : [Issue Tracker on a similar issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129316035).

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalSunmiRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':data:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1-alpha01.
     Required by:
         project :data
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1-alpha01'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.0.0-rc01' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-rc01'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1-alpha01'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1-alpha01'
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.1-alpha01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.1-alpha01
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.1-alpha01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.1-alpha01
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.1-alpha01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.1-alpha01

   > Could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01.
     Required by:
         project :data
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.room:room-runtime' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.0.0-rc01' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01'    

   > Could not resolve androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.0.0-rc01.
     Required by:
         project :data
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite-framework:2.0.1' --> 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.0.1'
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01

   > Could not resolve android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1.
     Required by:
         project :data
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.room:room-runtime' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.0.0-rc01' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01'

   > Could not resolve androidx.room:room-common:2.1.0-alpha06.
     Required by:
         project :data > androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06
         project :data > androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06
         project :data > androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06 > androidx.room:room-migration:2.1.0-alpha06
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.room:room-common' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.room:room-common:2.1.0-alpha06'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.0.0-rc01' --> 'androidx.room:room-common:2.0.0-rc01'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.room:room-common:2.1.0-alpha06'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.room:room-common:2.1.0-alpha06'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.room:room-migration:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.room:room-common:2.1.0-alpha06'
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-common' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-common' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-common' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01

   > Could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06.
     Required by:
         project :data > androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.room:room-runtime' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.0.0-rc01' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01'    

   > Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :data > androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06
         project :data > androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1-alpha01'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.0.0-rc01' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-rc01'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1-alpha01'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1-alpha01'
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.1-alpha01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.1-alpha01
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.1-alpha01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.1-alpha01
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.1-alpha01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.1-alpha01

   > Could not resolve androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1-alpha01.
     Required by:
         project :data > androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha03
         project :data > androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0-alpha03
         project :data > androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.1.0-alpha03
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1-alpha01'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.0.0-rc01' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-rc01'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1-alpha01'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.1.0-alpha03' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.1-alpha01'
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.1-alpha01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.1-alpha01
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.1-alpha01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.1-alpha01
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime' strictly '2.0.1-alpha01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.1-alpha01


   > Could not resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01.
     Required by:
         project :data > androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.0.0-rc01
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.room:room-runtime' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Constraint path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime' strictly '2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 2.0.0-rc01
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.1.0-alpha06' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06'
           Dependency path 'shopperapp:data:unspecified' --> 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.0.0-rc01' --> 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01'
```

The gradle file is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()

    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    flavorDimensions "default"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include buildABI
            universalApk false
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {

        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "myappid.com"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode build_version_code as Integer
        versionName build_version
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
}

dependencies {
    implementation(name: 'PayLib-release', ext: 'aar')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.arr'])
    implementation 'com.sunmi:sunmiui:1.1.22'

    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    })
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation project(':data')
    implementation 'com.github.Kunzisoft:Android-SwitchDateTimePicker:2.0'

    // RxJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.7'
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.0.0"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Has anybody been able to resolve this issue?

Comment: post your gradle file

Comment: @ManojPerumarath i have posted my gradle file

Comment: Did you upgrade an existing project to x?

Comment: i can successfully build your gradle. what i have done is that i removed "PayLib-release" and ":Data" from gradle as well "media, appcompat and recyclerview" version into "1.1.0-alpha04".

Comment: @android I did the same thing as you did and the errors still persist

Comment: my android studio version is 3.3 and also i'm using the same 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2' as yours

Comment: @android same android version as yours

Comment: @ManojPerumarath yes i did upgrade and existing project to android x

Comment: All i can do is share my gradle file

Comment: if you create new project then still it occurs? if not then create new project then migrate it to androidx and then put your dependency one by one in gradle. so we can get in which dependency there is problem

Comment: @ManojPerumarath resolved the please see my solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to use a dependency resolution strategy:

So for each item that has been highlighted that the project requires, I have added to my dependency resolution:

```
configurations.all
            {
                resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                    if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.room'
                            && !details.requested.name.contains('room-runtime')) {
                        details.useVersion "2.1.0-alpha04"
                    }
                    if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.room'
                            && !details.requested.name.contains('room-testing')) {
                        details.useVersion "2.1.0-alpha04"
                    }
                    if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.room'
                            && !details.requested.name.contains('room-rxjava2')) {
                        details.useVersion "2.1.0-alpha04"
                    }
                    if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.room'
                            && !details.requested.name.contains('room-common')) {
                        details.useVersion "2.1.0-alpha04"
                    }
                    if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.room'
                            && !details.requested.name.contains('room-migration')) {
                        details.useVersion "2.1.0-alpha04"
                    }
                    if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.room'
                            && !details.requested.name.contains('room-compiler')) {
                        details.useVersion "2.1.0-alpha04"
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here I have stated that they should use version 2.1.0-alpha04 as it seems that version 2.1.0-alpha06 has issues from firsthand experiences as well as stated in another post: [Room persistence library (dependency issue), MVVM design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323595/room-persistence-library-dependency-issue-mvvm-design-pattern) and [Note: Failed to read get kotlin metadata for ...etc, and type converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381077/note-failed-to-read-get-kotlin-metadata-for-etc-and-type-converter)

Answer (score 2):

Try to update to the latest version of "com.google.gms:google-services" (it helped me).